# How to restart apache server automatically on window server?

Tags: php, windows, apache

i have a big system and query load on my apache server so crash when more query fire on mysql

how can i restart my apache server automatically when it stop?

Comment: This depends upon what WAMP stack you are using.

Comment: i am using apache server live window server not on localhost

Answer (score 3):

Automatically restart your Apache web server when it crashes or stops serving pages

Please follow the link, i think it will definitely help you out

[Automatically restart your apache server](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/ServiceProtector/Services/KeepApacheWindowsServiceRunning24x7.html)